# Using Jquery How to store value in var

Tags: jquery

here i'm new to Jquery please Helpme How to store value in var Like

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Btn1').click(function () {
                var Txtvalue= $('#txtxname').text();

                alert(Txtvalue)
            })
        })

<input type="button" id="Btn1" />
    <input type="text" id="txtxname">
```

Comment: Input elements don't have `.text()`, they have `.val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Btn1').click(function () {
                var ss = $('input#txtxname').val();
                alert(ss)
            })
        })

    </script>
```